# Disable the legends of a specific series in extJs chart

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have multiple series in a chart, but I don't want to show all those legends for the chart. How can I disable the legend for a specific series. Is there any way to do that in extJS?

```
series({
    axis: "left",
    type: "corescatter-series",
    xField: "AVG_ACTIVE_USERS",
    yField: "AVG_LOAD_AVG",
    totalKey: undefined
},{
    type: "coreline",
    axis: "left",
    xField: "AVG_ACTIVE_USERS",
    yField: "AVG_USAGE"
})
```

Here I want to disable the legends of coreline series.

Comment: What version of ExtJS you use. Look like ExtReact

Comment: @pvlt Using ExtJs iteself. Above code is the series config from the browser console. ExtJS version is 6.5.2

Comment: do you want to `disable` the legend, or `hidding` will do

Comment: The final result is not to show the legend on the UI. If hiding does that job, yes that would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Series` has property [showInLegend](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.chart.series.Series.html#cfg-showInLegend). You can set it to `false` for hidding series from `legend`

Comment: It does the work in below fiddle, but facing some issue at my end I guess. Will further dig, thanks man.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b7d&view/editor

Comment: Update : I had hasCustomLegend set to true and was over writing showInLegend flag. It is working now.